# How can I import a tree made with geometry nodes into unity?

Tags: 3d-view, unity, geometry-nodes, instances

So I made a tree with geometry nodes and to have a nice crown I instanced a lot of branches. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mkJg6BZ65k
I want to import this tree into Unity.

I realized the instances to make a single mesh, but it became a really high poly mesh. It's literally impossible to UV unwrap it, so I can't bake textures. Is there any way, to UV unwrap only 1 branch and the base of the tree onto a single image and tell the instances to use the UV texture from this image?
Something like he does at 5:07 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrXZNG4yAa8&t=345s Here he has only 1 leaf on the UV map, yet on the mesh all the leafs use that part of the UV map.

You can find the .FBX and .BLEND files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q65u3Pf2utAFqM-MnEINlLLyMt6uAK9M?usp=sharing

If you can help me with any of these problems please don't hold back, I would be really thankful!

Comment: Can you "Apply" the GN in the modifiers properties tab.

Comment: The base of the tree is a Curve and I can't apply the GN while it's not a single mesh. If I convert it to a mesh, all the instances disappear. Sorry, I edited the question to just one topic.